# Should I be using GTK threads/Good tutorials on GTK threading?

Tags: c, multithreading, user-interface, gtk, xlib

This is my scenario so far:

I am trying to build a GUI using GTK in C. In the middle of the GUI will be a screen displaying video input. The video input window is a XLIB window which I am (currently unsuccessfully trying to) wrap in a GTK widget. Around it however will be buttons etc.. to interact with the video or do things according to the video output.

I am wondering if this would be the correct time to use threads as I want my GTK GUI to be running while the video input/processing is being displayed. If so any good guides, if not what would you recommend?

From @bash.d's comments I should be using threading, does anyone know any good links or where in the man pages I should be looking as I seem to be getting more confused and coming across deprecated functions.

Comment: When you want your UI to stay responsive, you won't get around threads at all... It is possible to use, i.e., `pthreads`, too. But I read this can lead to clashes and you should use `GTK` threads.

Comment: @bash.d thanks do you also know any good links to GTK threading in C ?

Comment: The [official documentation](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php) should give you plenty of ideas, I hope.

Comment: I have to recommend you to use [Gstreamer][1] if you're planning to add media to your application and planning on use Gtk+. It's better to keep yourself in the loop. Use compatibles toolkits and you're coding will be easy. Also, you better avoid threading altogether outside Gtk+, better use GLib support for async operations.

[1]: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Answer (score 3):

I would discourage you from using threads if your only reason for doing so is to keep your UI responsive. Instead, you should call

```
while (gtk_events_pending())
    gtk_main_iteration();
```

at certain points during your video processing.

Answer (score 1):

I think thread is the right way to go. Here is a good tutorial [multi-threaded gtk+ application](http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/06/multi-threaded-gtk-applications.html)

Comment: Actually, that is not the correct way to do it anymore. It's been depricated.